# File share over site-to-site VPN (DFS enabled)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, site-to-site-vpn, dfs

I have two sites with servers with DFS and one site with just two VPN site-to-site to the other two sites with the servers.
The users can't acess the file share via \\domain.local\SHARE but they can access via already mapped drive like T:\SHARE .
The problem is that some software like adobe and progeCAD while opening the files they say "Can't find somefile.pdf" or "somefile.dwg".
This is strange. All DNS are configured correctly. They can ping all servers. They can access the server like: \\theserverip\ and see all visiable shares. But once they double click the share it just pops out an error saying the windows couldn't find the place.
All shares are mapping to the users via GPO.

Someone got into this situation and found the solution or workarround?

edit 1: message is this (translated):

Check the spelling in the name. Otherwise, there is a problem with a network. To try to identify and resolve network problems, click Diagnostics.
**[Expanded Information]
Error code: 0x80070035**

edit 2: I can access non DFS shares without problems. It seems DFS enabled shares are affected with this problem.